# batch script variable unset in for loop has no effect

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, local-variables, unset

Below is my script. I am trying to look into folders one level below and pick out only those folders, hence the ~-9 which extracts the last 9 chars from the path. But the set var= does not unset the variable because the output comes back with the same folder name repeated # times. Also batch doesn't allow me to do this extract trick directly on %%i, hence the need for the local variable.

How do I clear this variable so that it takes the new value in the next iteration?

```
@echo off
 for /d %%i in (%1\*) do (
  set var=%%i
  echo %var:~-9%
   set "var="
)
```

Answer (score 2):

http://judago.webs.com/variablecatches.htm has an explanation for my problem. The magic lines were setlocal enabledelayedexpansion and calling var as echo !var:~-9!. ! vs % ...wow! cmd still amazes me.

Comment: +1, good job finding the source of your problem. You still have a [potential problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11440780/1012053) if names contain `!`.

Answer (score 0):

You found the source of your problem, as well as the solution - delayed expansion.

But using FOR while delayed expansion is enabled can cause problems if any of the filenames contain the `!` character. The expansion of the for variable `%%i` will be corrupted if the value contains `!` and delayed expansion is enabled. This is not a frequent problem, but it happens.

The solution is to toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%i in (%1\*) do (
  set var=%%i
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo !var:~-9!
  endlocal
)
```

I'm also wondering what you mean by *"I am trying to look into folders one level below and pick out only those folders, hence the ~-9 which extracts the last 9 chars from the path"*. I suspect your are trying to get the name of the child folder, without the leading path information. If that is so, then using the substring operation is not a good solution because the length of folder names varies.

There is a very simple method to get the name of the folder without the leading path info:

```
for /d %%i in (%1\*) do echo %%~nxi
```